# How can I better store a string to avoid many clones?

Tags: rust, traits

I am using tokio's [`UdpCodec`](https://docs.rs/tokio-core/0.1.4/tokio_core/net/trait.UdpCodec.html) trait:

```
pub trait UdpCodec {
    type In;
    type Out;
    fn decode(&mut self, src: &SocketAddr, buf: &[u8]) -> Result<Self::In>;
    fn encode(&mut self, msg: Self::Out, buf: &mut Vec<u8>) -> SocketAddr;
}
```

My associated type for `In` is a `(SocketAddr, Vec<Metric>)`. `Metric` is defined as:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Metric {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: f64,
    pub metric_type: MetricType,
    pub sample_rate: Option<f64>,
}
```

I have used owned strings to avoid lifetime constraints with the associated types. However I also do `HashMap` lookups and inserts with these metric names which involves a lot of cloning since I borrow metrics in other functions.

How can I better store a string within this `Metric` type to avoid many inefficient clones? Using the `Cow` type has crossed my mind but it also obviously has a lifetime association.

Comment: Perhaps the names come from a small set, and you'd like to intern the strings? Rather than Cow, you'd like to always have the same string value refer to some lightweight identifier?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove the clones but will not allow for the use of lifetimes?

Comment: I guess I should have clarified that I can't use lifetimes in associated types right? It seemed to me that it's a form of HKT.

Comment: I'm open to any suggestion as I have struggled trying to use string slices and the `Cow` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on @Josh's suggestion, I would suggest using interning.

Depending on how memory or CPU intensive your task is, make your pick between:

- A double hash-map: `ID` <-> `String`, shared between components
- A single hash-map: `String` -> `Rc<str>`

If you can afford the latter, I definitely advise it. Also note that you can likely fold `MetricType` within the `Rc`: `Rc<(MetricType, str)>`.

Then you still need to call `clone` left and right, but each is just a cheap non-atomic increment operation... and moving to multithread is as simple as swapping `Arc` for `Rc`.

Comment: I think an `Rc<String>` is a simple fix, yes. I totally overlooked that. My `MetricType` is an enum. I'm purely concerned with a `Metric`'s name field in this case.

Comment: Note: `Rc<String>` implies two indirections, use `Rc<str>` instead if possible.

Comment: Is it possible to make an `Rc<str>`? I did some research and am looking into the owning_ref crate for now.

Comment: @squiguy: The type accepts it, but I can find no way to instantiate such a type because `new` doesn't... bummer...